# Can Ableton add another instrument layer every time a loop repeats whilst live?

Tags: recording, midi, ableton-live

Say I'm working with an 8-bar drum beat. If I want to add another instrument layer on top I must stop recording the drums, arm the new instrument, and then press the record button, wait for the count-in, and record over the drums. For 8 bars. And I just repeat this process. And it works even when I'm performing live.

I'm wondering if I can immediately stop recording one instrument, and then by the time the loop begins, arm another instrument and start recording. This way every 8 bars I add a new instrument to the track. Whilst performing live. Does Ableton have this feature?

Comment: I have worked with a beatbox artist who would do this with a fairly sophisticated foot controller. I am not aware of the specifics of the device programming, but as far as I know it is entirely possible. Perhaps an Ableton user group/forum might have some more useful info.

Comment: Is this related https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/setting-up-ableton-live-as-a-live-looper

Comment: Yea @piiperi that might answer the question, except unfortunately the link provided in the top answer is dead